# I am using Chrome and cant get image to show from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, image

Firstly I know I shouldn't put the image in a DB but I am still learning.

I want to show the image, where am I going wrong?

In my database I have a column **Image** that is a BLOB. Small sized image. And I've checked an image array is there.

After I connect the db here is the php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Image FROM table WHERE ID = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row["image"];
```

Any help appreciated.

All I want is just the image to show. Nothing fancy as I will expand on it once I get an image up on the screen.

I think I need an extra step between fetch array to split a variable that contains just the image and to display that. This is where I get lost.

Cheers.

This is the code I use to update the DB (from a form)

```
  $myphoto = $_FILES['MyPhoto'];
  $query = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Image = '$myphoto' WHERE ID = 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `image` and `Image` are different

Comment: "I know I shouldn't put the image in a DB" - It depends. But probably not in this instance by the sounds of it.

Comment: Image is the Column heading in Mysql.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `echo` an HTML `<image>` tag with the `src` set to your query results to render an image.  Use this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Image FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Looks like I am further but the result is a broken image. When I look at the result source it states that its a 20px x 20px yet the image stored in mysql db is larger??? I have cleared the cache and still wont show. Is there a problem with Chrome using the HTML tag. Im sure the image is there it just wont display.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you use to store the image as a blob into your database.

Comment: Sorry, was watching a TV drama. It isnt solved as I have a broken picture.

Comment: WOW I got it to work..... and its with your statement Tim..... I cant vote but I am happy to find out how to save it was you who got it working!

Comment: Please mark the answer correct...click the check mark under the score.